# PHP Mess Detector for Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, unit-testing, phpmd

I have the PTI Eclipse plugin installed.

There is a possibility to change `PDepend`, `CodeSniffer` and `UnitTest`

When I try right-clicking on any file I have a `Mess Detector` option as well but nothing happens when I click it. And after searching all configuration options, I and can't find any settings for `PHPMD`.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Have you installed the PHP Mess Detector using PEAR or Composer?  I do not use Eclipse, but I believe the PDT bundle includes these, and you could therefore install and use the tool.

Comment: @StevenScott I've installed it with PEAR

Comment: @Jonast92 No updates yet.

Comment: every one just fixing grammar, no one posting answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Old question but since there still seems to be interest in it... I just installed the PTI plugin and there was no mention of PHPMD so I wonder where you get the "Mess Detection" menu item from?

For me actually nothing of PTI works with Eclipse Kepler SR2. Whatever I try just nothing happens.

I'd recommend you MakeGood for running PHPUnit tests in Eclipse and setting up Jenkins (including PHPMD) for your project, it takes a bit time to set up but once it is running it is just great: [Template for Jenkins Jobs for PHP Projects](http://jenkins-php.org/)

Comment: I do have UnitTests, Jenkins running my build.xml and going thru everything like mess detection, complexity analyse, codesniffer, etc... I have even written an article: http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2012/12/continuous-integration-for-symfony2-using-jenkins/

But I'd like to have PHPMD errors to be highlighted in my IDE :) I found it in another IDE, but still, would be nice to have it in Eclipse.

Comment: @IliaShakitko +1 for **Jenkins**. There you can have all what you want. _PHPMD_ + _CPD_, _CodeCoverage_ etc. A bit more headache with configuration probably, but configs are the same as for plugins for Eclipse. And _Jenkins_ gives you valuable experience in _Continuous Integration_ :).

Answer (score -1):

When PHPMD runs, it first searches for a **default** PHP executable which must exist, and this is **not** set in "PHP Tools" but in "PHP":

```
Window > Preferences > PHP > PHP Executables > (choose one) > [SET DEFAULT]
```

But if you had not done this, you would have gotten an error.

At this point PHPMD runs, and places its output in the PHPMD view (not in the Console view), which is usually displayed at the bottom. If it does not appear at all, it might have been closed or ignored. So:

```
Window > Show View > PHP Tools (Others?) > PHPMD
```

Another thing that may happen is that PHPMD detects nothing (the view appears but it is empty). In that case you can check the Console view to see what happened. Otherwise, you *could* try and modify the phpmd.php script which is run by PTI so that it logs what it's doing (you might for example wrap the main routine in a try/catch), either to stdout or by opening a temporary file somewhere on your system.