# PHPMD (PHP Mess Detector) integration in Eclipse Mars

Tags: php, eclipse, phpcodesniffer, phpmd

Before the release of Mars it was possible to install PHPMD support in Eclipse, albeit with [some caveats and difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32284710/1428679).

Now support from PTI seems to have been removed completely, even if [development of PHPMD hasn't stopped](http://phpmd.org/) and PHPMD does offer some features that other tools do not: for example, [detect unused variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854592/best-method-to-recognize-unused-variables).

<sup>For this last feature I've found a [not too recent CodeSniffer plugin](https://github.com/illusori/PHP_Codesniffer-VariableAnalysis) that does the trick. There are also [some sniffs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/CodeAnalysis/UnusedFunctionParameterSniff.php) that should do the work but they don't seem to work for me, or not in all cases at the very least: I have a project in need of refactoring for which I have 11 warnings from CodeSniffer and 2524 from PHPMD.</sup>

I think I have a simple and inelegant way of shoehorning PHPMD back in, but before doing *that*, I wondered whether anyone has this specific same problem/need, and whether s/he managed to solve it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here goes.

I do have a PHPMD binary that works from the command line. What I planned to do is to **inject its output into that of the CodeSniffer plugin**, to "enrich" the latter with PHPMD messages.

To this effect, I mangled `phpcs.php` which comes in my `plugins/org.ppsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.codesniffer_.../php/tools` directory.

(Since another problem I have with CodeSniffer is that it will often re-scan files it *ought* to know about, I decided to give CodeSniffer a memory.

First thing, I extract the last argument to the invocation, which is the file being analyzed (lines marked by +++ are my additions/changes):

```
// Optionally use PHP_Timer to print time/memory stats for the run.
// Note that the reports are the ones who actually print the data
// as they decide if it is ok to print this data to screen.
@include_once 'PHP/Timer.php';
if (class_exists('PHP_Timer', false) === true) {
    PHP_Timer::start();
}

if (is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php') === true) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
} else {
    include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
}

+++ $lastArgument   = array_pop($_SERVER['argv']);
```

Then I add some flags that CS doesn't seem to pass, and that I need, such as ignoring some directories:

```
+++ $_SERVER['argv'][]  = '--ignore=tests,vendor,cache';
+++ $_SERVER['argv'][]  = $lastArgument;
```

Then CS invocation proceeds, but now I save its results to a buffer instead of sending them straight to Eclipse.

```
$phpcs = new PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI();
$phpcs->checkRequirements();
+++ ob_start();
$numErrors = $phpcs->process();

+++ $dom    = new DOMDocument();
+++ $dom->loadXML(ob_get_clean());

+++ $cs     = $dom->getElementsByTagName('phpcs')->item(0);
+++ $xpath  = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Now I have PHPCS output ready as XML.

All that remains is to invoke PHPMD using its own syntax.

```
// Add PHPMD.
$mdCmd  = "C:/PHP/composer/vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd \"{$lastArgument}\" xml \"C:/Program Files/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/data/PHP_PMD/resources/rulesets/codesize.xml,C:/Program Files/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/data/PHP_PMD/resources/rulesets/naming.xml,C:/Program Files/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/data/PHP_PMD/resources/rulesets/unusedcode.xml\"";
```

...and load it into another XML:

```
    fprintf(STDERR, $mdCmd . "\n");
    $dompmd = new DOMDocument();
    $dompmd->loadXML($mdxml = shell_exec($mdCmd));
```

Now I get all errors out of the PMD object, and add it to the CS one:

```
    $files  = $dompmd->getElementsByTagName('file');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name   = $file->getAttribute('name');
        $list   = $xpath->query("//file[@name=\"{$name}\"]");
        if (null === $list) {
            continue;
        }
        $csFile = $list->item(0);
        if (null === $csFile) {
            // No errors from CS.
            $csFile = $dom->createElement('file');
            $csFile->setAttribute('name', $name);
            $csFile->setAttribute('errors', 0);
            $csFile->setAttribute('warnings', 0);
            $csFile->setAttribute('fixable', 0);
            $cs->appendChild($csFile);
        }
        $errs   = 0;
        foreach ($file->childNodes as $violation) {
            if ($violation instanceof \DOMText) {
                continue;
            }
            $error  = $dom->createElement('warning', trim($violation->nodeValue));


            $error->setAttribute('line', $violation->getAttribute('beginline'));
            $error->setAttribute('column', 1);
            $error->setAttribute('source', 'PHPMD.' . $violation->getAttribute('ruleset'));
            $error->setAttribute('severity', $violation->getAttribute('priority'));
            $error->setAttribute('fixable', 0);

            $csFile->appendChild($error);

            $errs++;
        }
        $csFile->getAttributeNode('errors')->value += $errs;
    }
```

Finally, send the data back to Eclipse:

```
print $dom->saveXML();
exit($numErrors ? 1: 0);
```

## Caching CodeSniffer (and PHPMD too)

Since another problem I have with CodeSniffer is that it will often re-scan files it *ought* to know about, I decided to give CodeSniffer a memory. It's pretty easy: I can store a temporary file with the saved XML and a name built up of the MD5 of the original file name *and* its contents:

```
/tmp/68ce1959ef67bcc94e05084e2e20462a.76e55e72f32156a20a183de82fe0b3b6.xml
```

So when PHPCS is asked to analyze `/path/to/file/so-and-so.php`, it will:

- create the MD5 of the filename.
- create the MD5 of its contents.
- if /tmp/md5file.md5content.xml does not exist:

  - delete any /tmp/md5file.*.xml there are: they're obsolete.
  - run code as above.
  - save results into /tmp/md5file.md5content.xml
- output the content of /tmp/md5file.md5content.xml .